# App Rejected by google play store due to permissions handler

Tags: java, android, google-play, android-permissions

I am doing internal testing on my app for Google Play Store but every time my app gets rejected by Google with the following reply:

> Requested permissions do not match core functionality of the app You
>   declared Default SMS handler (and any other core functionality usage
>   while default handler) as the core functionality of your app. However,
>   after review, we found that your app does not match the declared use
>   case(s). Learn more about permitted uses and exceptions. Please
>   either: • Make changes to your app so that it meets the requirements
>   of the declared core functionality or, • Select a use case that
>   matches your app’s functionality

I do not know why it happen even I have already declared all permission which I used in my app.
Please help me how I can resolve it.

Comment: The Default SMS Handler declaration is a valid declaration only if your app will exhibit behaviour that is appropriate for an SMS application (think of the Messages app on your phone). Why are you asking for the default SMS Handler declaration? Can you please clarify in your question?
Also for more information check out - https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/default-handlers#follow-requirements-default-handlers

Comment: Thanks for the review Saket, Actually I am doing the backup messages app functionality and I need this functionality with permissions SMS_READ, SMS_WRITE. Over all functiaonlity working fine in the app but Google Play Store recjeted my app for Internal Testing.

Comment: What kind of internal testing do you want to do? Perhaps there is an approach that doesn't necessarily need you to upload to Google Play Store right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, your app description on the Play Store is probably not making it clear why you need the Default SMS Handler.

The Default SMS Handler permission/attribute is used by the Android OS to understand whether to ask the user whether they would like to set your app as the default SMS application. From [Developer Android resources](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/default-handlers#follow-requirements-default-handlers):

> Given the sensitive user information that an app accesses while
>   serving as a default handler, your app cannot become a default handler
>   unless it meets the following Play Store listing and core
>   functionality requirements:
>
> Your app must be able to perform the functionality for which it's a
>   default handler. For example, a default SMS handler should be able to
>   send text messages.
>
> - Your app must provide a privacy policy.
> - Your app must make its core functionality clear in the Play Store description. For example, a default Phone handler should describe its
>     phone-related capabilities in the description.
> - Your app must declare permissions that are appropriate for its use case. For more details about which permissions you can declare as a
>     given handler, see the guidance on using SMS or call log permission
>     groups in the Play Console Help Center.
> - Your app must ask to become a default handler before it requests the permissions associated with being that handler. For example, an
>     app must request to become the default SMS handler before it requests
>     the READ_SMS permission.

Here's what I would do if I were you:

- Add a privacy policy.
- Indicate in your Play Store listing why someone might want your app to be the default SMS app (Will a user be able to read and send messages to others? If so I would suggest mentioning that).
- Add functionality to send SMS as well (I get it that this might not be what you are looking to do from your app, but it seems like Google has increased importance on privacy regarding user SMSes)

Comment: I have declared the above all declaraton as google guidance and I had also changed defaut handler to Backup and Restore in the Permissions Declaration Form but still rejection appear.

Comment: "Unable to verify core functionality of app
When you submitted your app, you specified your app's core functionality as follows: Backup and restore for users. However, we couldn’t find evidence that the app offers the declared core functionality during our review. Please submit an updated Permissions Declaration Form that includes instructions on how to verify your declared functionality, and include details such as test account information. If portions of your app are restricted, please share a link to a video of your app to help us verify the core functionalities you’ve declared."

Answer (score 1):

SMS and Call Log Permissions are regarded as personal and sensitive user data subject to the Personal and Sensitive Information policy, and the following restrictions:
Restricted Permission   Requirement
Call Log permission group (e.g. READ_CALL_LOG, WRITE_CALL_LOG, PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS)  It must be actively registered as the default Phone or Assistant handler on the device.
SMS permission group (e.g. READ_SMS, SEND_SMS, WRITE_SMS, RECEIVE_SMS, RECEIVE_WAP_PUSH, RECEIVE_MMS)   It must be actively registered as the default SMS or Assistant handler on the device.

**Apps lacking default SMS, Phone, or Assistant handler capability may not declare use of the above permissions in the manifest**. This includes placeholder text in the manifest. Additionally, apps must be actively registered as the default SMS, Phone, or Assistant handler before prompting users to accept any of the above permissions and must immediately stop using the permission when they’re no longer the default handler. The permitted uses and exceptions are available on this Help Center page.

Apps may only use the permission (and any data derived from the permission) to provide approved core app functionality Core functionality is defined as the main purpose of the app. This may include a set of core features, which must all be prominently documented and promoted in the app’s description. Without the core feature(s), the app is “broken” or rendered unusable. The transfer, sharing, or licensed use of this data must only be for providing core features or services within the app, and its use may not be extended for any other purpose (e.g., improving other apps or services, advertising, or marketing purposes). You may not use alternative methods (including other permissions, APIs, or third-party sources) to derive data attributed to Call Log or SMS related permissions.
Check google documentation for reference -
https://play.google.com/about/privacy-security-deception/permissions/#!?zippy_activeEl=sms-call-permissions#sms-call-permissions

Comment: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9047303

Comment: https://play.google.com/about/privacy-security-deception/permissions/#!?zippy_activeEl=sms-call-permissions#sms-call-permissions

Comment: Done, Have added it